# PyQt5 - QTableWidget horizontal scroll bar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a table that I would like to update items on a mouse button click. So far, the update works *almost* flawlessly. I'm running into an odd issue that when I click the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of my table widget, it registers the click as clicking the first item in the column directly above the mouse.

I'm running python 3.7, pyqt5.

Here's the table:

```
class PlotTable(QTableWidget):

    removed_column = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    update_table = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, rows=0, columns=0, parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, rows, columns, parent)
        self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if item is not None and isinstance(item, QTableWidgetItem):
                if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
                    col = item.column()
                    self.removeColumn(col)
                    self.removed_column.emit(col)
                elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.update_table.emit(item)

        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

The goal is to either update a table selection or remove a column from the table, depending on the click type. I thought perhaps filtering for a QTableWidgetItem would prevent the accidental scroll bar update, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll bar is inside the QTableWidget's `contentsRect`, so when you get the `itemAt(event.pos())`, it still works even if you click on the scroll bar. You could get the geometry of the scroll bar, and only perform the actions if the event position is not inside that area.

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        if not self.horizontalScrollBar().geometry().contains(event.pos()):
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item, QTableWidgetItem):
                if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
                    col = item.column()
                    self.removeColumn(col)
                    self.removed_column.emit(col)
                elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.update_table.emit(item)

    return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Or you could just reimplement the `mousePressEvent` which will ignore the clicks to the scroll bar by default.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
        col = self.currentColumn()
        self.removeColumn(col)
        self.removed_column.emit(col)
    elif event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.update_table.emit(self.currentItem())
```

Comment: change `if item is not None and isinstance(item, QTableWidgetItem):` to `if isinstance(item, QTableWidgetItem):`. Your code is redundant.

Comment: Ok, I just copied it from the question